# Rails 3 Validation Question (Rspec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

Completely stumped by this.  I swear, this looks like it should work but it doesnt.  The testing database has been updated (rake db:migrate - rake:db:test:clone).  I'm hoping I'm doing something silly.

Full disclosure, I'm running the 3.1 RC4.

**Model**

```
class ExerciseSet < ActiveRecord::Base

  TYPES = %w[time rep]

  validates :type,
            :presence => true,
            :inclusion => { :in => TYPES }

end
```

**Spec File**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ExerciseSet do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = { :value => 12, 
              :value_max => 15,
              :type => "timed",
              :target => "range"
    }            
  end


  describe "type" do
    it "must be either 'time' or 'rep'" do
      values = %w[time rep]
      values.each do |value|
        exercise_instance = ExerciseSet.new(@attr.merge(:type  => value))
        exercise_instance.should be_valid
      end
    end
  end

end
```

**Output**

```
Failures:

  1) ExerciseSet type must be either 'time' or 'rep'
     Failure/Error: exercise_instance.should be_valid
       expected valid? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/models/exercise_set_spec.rb:19:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/exercise_set_spec.rb:17:in `each'
     # ./spec/models/exercise_set_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first - why isn't the instance valid? I'd be adding some debugging to the spec:

```
describe "type" do
  it "must be either 'time' or 'rep'" do
    values = %w[time rep]
    values.each do |value|
      exercise_instance = ExerciseSet.new(@attr.merge(:type  => value))
      exercise_instance.valid? # force errors
      puts exercise_instance.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
      exercise_instance.should be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

Yes, this should probably be a comment, but then I couldn't offer the spec rewrite so easily.

Comment: Great question.  Thanks for the debugging tip; I was wondering how to do that.  I'll play with the print statements and see what I can find out.  Still trying to figure this ruby/rails thing out coming from the Java world.

Comment: Thanks to Pat's suggestion of using print statements, I figured this out.  I pulled the object.new statement from the block, and updated the type field in the block each time I looped through the array.  Code is listed in the post above.  I'm still curious as to why the first design failed though.

Comment: You don't have an `attr_accessible` call in the model, do you?

Comment: Nope, just the core base class and the validation.

Comment: For debugging, I find it better to include the errors as part of the tests assertions:
`exercise_instance.errors.full_messages.join("\n").should eq("")`
That way, RSpec would print out the validations erros together with the test info.